# No type specified for controller.create

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have just ugraded to extjs5.1 and get this error thrown

> No type specified for controller.create

which is thrown from here :

> Ext.ClassManager.Ext.apply.create @ ext-all-debug.js:8894
>   PackageGroupController.openPopUpView @ PackageGroupController.js:171

I am simply creating my own custom dialog :

```
this.packageGroupDialog = Ext.create('js.packageGroup.PackageGroupDialog', {
    packetName: _this.groupName,
    controller: _this,
    outletRowClass: _this.outletSelectionController.outletRowClass, //for rendering
    outletGroupRowClass: _this.outletSelectionController.outletGroupRowClass, //for rendering
    toDeliverListeners_OutletGroup: _this.outletSelectionController.toDeliverListeners_forOutletGroup,
    toDeliverListeners_Outlet: _this.outletSelectionController.toDeliverListeners_forOutlet,
    outletOnlyMode: false,
    isMcArea: _this.isMcArea,
    groupId: _this.groupId,
    isMcAreaRestricted: _this.isMcAreaRestricted
});
```

I haven't changed the code or anything.

Comment: its where i create my dialog

Comment: but i think i found an answer to my question. controller is now reserverd in extjs5. I will post answer in a minute

Answer (score 0):

I realised the problem is that ExtJS5 has 'controller' reserved for GUI components. So If I am creating my dialog above and passing my own 'controller' into the configuration, it is overriding the extjs5 controller and giving it something it doesn't expect.

So, in short, I just renamed the 'controller' to something like 'controllerPG'